# Set empty value for enum datatype in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have column `'colors'` with data type `'ENUM'` in `'profile'` table.

The following `values` are used for 'colors' column and this 'profile' table has more than `1K records`.

```
- Black
- White
- Red
- Orange

enum('Black', 'White', 'Red', 'Orange')
```

Now I want to `set empty value for 'colors' column` for some scenarios while inserting records.

So I just tried to add one record with empty value through phpmyadmin and it is working fine

```
insert into `profile` (user_id, colors) values ('10000', '');
```

My question is, I don't have empty value for 'colors' column. However, it is working fine.

```
So shall I continue without altering schema for 'colors' column
```

**(or)**

```
Should I alter the schema as follows
ALTER TABLE `profile` CHANGE `colors` `method` ENUM( '', 'Black', 'White', 'Red', 'Orange' )
```

Please suggest the best practice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would use  NULL in this case

Comment: So do you suggest to add NULL value instead of empty value (or) make it as nullable column. in this case, I need to alter the schema.

Comment: also you don't need to add `''` to allow empty for enum that works by default

Comment: im suggesting altering the schema for `NULL` but by the looks its no big deal blank or null - NULL just feels correct to me

Comment: oh excellent, thats why its working when I add records with empty value. could you please add some more details with answer. I will approve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somewhat changing my mind from my comments:

NULL - for data absence
blank - for actively picking that as the colour(if that makes sense)

as to how **enum** works:

It allows blank by default and NULL when your schema allows it.

Ref:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: Thank you Dagon for clarified this :)

Comment: So I don't have a plan to alter schema. Just continue to add empty value.

Comment: if that works - its business logic here not programming :-)